# Why do two blessings in the amidah start with the letter “vov” translated as “and”

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, text

In the text of all my Ashkenaz siddurim, the following blessings in the Amidah start with the letter “vov” translated as “and”:

1] The blessing ולמלשינים against informers which follows the blessing for justice.

2] The blessing ולירושלים for the rebuilding of Jerusalem which follows the blessing for the righteous.

Do the commentators explain that the “vov” links the blessing to the one before and so

only after the establishment of  justice could the informers be dealt with

and Jerusalem will only be rebuilt in the merit of the righteous?

Comment: FWIW not everyone agrees those start with a Vav, not even all Ashkenzi ones.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK  - edited to take account of your comment. Which nuschaos don't have the vov please?

Comment: Sefardim have למינים ולמלשינים. I suspect censorship may have been involved in producing the ashkenazi version...